# How to send multiple response using node js

Tags: node.js

How to send multiple responses to client using node.js want to know how to send immediate response to client and continue the request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal HTTP can only deliver one response per request. Consider sending it all at once or look into push technologies such as WebSockets [socket.io](http://socket.io)

Comment: Ok Thanks, can you let me know any websites which we can send multiple response to client